# How to design circle progress bar in ionic 3?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

how to create circular progress bar in ionic 3. i am new in ionic.
i already tried to install

```
npm install jquery-circle-progress
```

[package link here](https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress)

it installed perfect but i am confuse that how to use it in ionic? 
please guide me.Thanks in advance

**Update:**

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
 import { ProfilePage } from './profile';
 import { RoundProgressComponent } from 'angular-svg-round-progressbar'; 

       @NgModule({ 
           declarations: [ ProfilePage, ],
           imports: [IonicPageModule.forChild(ProfilePage), ], }) 

           export class ProfilePageModule {}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update: 06-11-2017**

This is not working with the latest version (`1.2.0`). But it is working fine with `npm install angular-svg-round-progressbar@1.1.1 --save`.

[**Working git repo**](https://github.com/Sampath-Lokuge/svgapp):

Another [**Answer is here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47122910/1077309)

**Old Answer:**

You **can't** use above mentioned **jquery progress bar** with Ionic.You have to use an Angular module for that.

Here is the one which you can use.

[**Demo**](http://crisbeto.github.io/angular-svg-round-progressbar/)

[**Git Repo**](https://github.com/crisbeto/angular-svg-round-progressbar)

[image]

**Steps:**

```
npm install angular-svg-round-progressbar --save
```

After that you need to import the `RoundProgressModule` in your `module` as shown below:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RoundProgressModule} from 'angular-svg-round-progressbar';

@NgModule({
  imports: [RoundProgressModule]
})
export class YourModule {};
```

**Update:**

```
import { RoundProgressComponent } from 'angular-svg-round-progressbar'; 

       @NgModule({ 
           declarations: [ ProfilePage, ],
           imports: [IonicPageModule.forChild(ProfilePage),
                     RoundProgressModule],
           }) 

           export class ProfilePageModule {}
```

Comment: how to import this package? please clear this issue
`import { RoundProgressComponent } from 'angular-svg-round-progressbar';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ProfilePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(ProfilePage),
    
  ],

})
export class ProfilePageModule {}`

Comment: Do you need any support from me or SOLVED?

Comment: this stuff is mostly done my issue but just clear me that how to import this library? when i am doing import that library it give me error.

Comment: Can you show the code on your page? Please put that on your question above.

Comment: i already mention the code in my previous comment of my module.ts. But i am going to mention it again. the following code is profile.module.ts file code. just explain me how to import that labrary
.
`import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ProfilePage } from './profile';

import { RoundProgressComponent } from 'angular-svg-round-progressbar';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ProfilePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(ProfilePage),
    
  ],

})
export class ProfilePageModule {}
`

Comment: Please see the **Update** on my post above.

Comment: yeah that's great. but the problem is when i add the `<round-progress [current]="30" [max]="100"></round-progress>` it give me error to 
`1. If 'round-progress' is an Angular component and it has 'current' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'round-progress' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.` what should i do now?? BTW thanks for helping

Comment: Have you imported this `RoundProgressModule` to the relevant page's module where you're using it?  I mean the view has `<round-progress>`?  If yes then reload the server again using `ionic serve`.

Comment: yes absolutely i have import `RoundProgressModule` in `profile.module.ts` file and `<round-progress>` tag on view. and also reload the server but it give me same error

Comment: Actually the error is `No provider for RoundProgressService`

Comment: Did you do this? `npm install angular-svg-round-progressbar --save`

Comment: If yes, can you give us a minimal git repo for testing that bug?

Comment: Sure.I'll test it tonight and will let you know.

Comment: @watsonic to solve it install v1.1.1

'npm install angular-svg-round-progressbar@1.1.1 --save' also I add it on 'app.module.ts'

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have updated the post :) @DanielGatti

Comment: @DanielGatti thanks. This worked for me. I had to do `npm uninstall angular-svg-round-progressbar` first