# Angular SVG round progressbar not work for Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Im read and install this `Angular SVG round progressbar` for my ionic project , but its not working for me,
https://github.com/crisbeto/angular-svg-round-progressbar

how to correctly added for this my page? please help me to fix this
 displayed this error

> ```
> Error: Template parse errors:
> Can't bind to 'current' since it isn't a known property of 'round-progress'.
> 1. If 'round-progress' is an Angular component and it has 'current' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'round-progress' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
> ```
>
> to suppress this message.
>       3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
>
> ```
>   <round-progress [ERROR ->][current]="48" [max]="100"></round-progress>
> </ion-content>
>
> ")
> ```

Thanks

my pages for im added **home.html**

```
<round-progress
    [current]="current"
    [max]="max"
    [color]="'#45ccce'"
    [background]="'#eaeaea'"
    [radius]="125"
    [stroke]="20"
    [semicircle]="true"
    [rounded]="true"
    [clockwise]="false"
    [responsive]="false"
    [duration]="800"
    [animation]="'easeInOutQuart'"
    [animationDelay]="0"
    (onRender)="doSomethingWithCurrentValue($event)"></round-progress>
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Component,NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {RoundProgressModule} from 'angular-svg-round-progressbar';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',


})
@NgModule({
  imports: [RoundProgressModule]
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private _config: RoundProgressConfig) {
 _config.setDefaults({
  color: '#f00',
  background: '#0f0'
});
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** You need to use an older version as shown below.The current version has an issue where I have mentioned below.

```
npm install angular-svg-round-progressbar@1.1.1 --save
```

[**Working Git Repo is here**](https://github.com/Sampath-Lokuge/svgapp)

You just need to add it to your page's module as shown below.

*home.module.ts*

```
import {RoundProgressModule} from 'angular-svg-round-progressbar';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage),
    RoundProgressModule
  ],
})
export class HomePageModule { }
```

**Note:**

It seems to have a new issue with this module.I have logged it. We have to wait till they'll give the solution.[**Git issue is here**](https://github.com/crisbeto/angular-svg-round-progressbar/issues/144).

Comment: Please see the **Update**

Comment: sir i had following error Error: Template parse errors: `
Can't bind to 'current' since it isn't a known property of 'round-progress'.
1. If 'round-progress' is an Angular component and it has 'current' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'round-progress' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("`

Comment: Can you fork this repo? It is working fine:https://github.com/Sampath-Lokuge/svgapp

Comment: Sir your `Repo` is getting error Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unexpected value 'RoundProgressModule' imported by the module 'HomePageModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
Error: Unexpected value 'RoundProgressModule' imported by the module 'HomePageModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Comment: Did you run the `npm i`? Can you show the `package.json` file?

Comment: Sir im used for ionic `3.16.0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158303/discussion-between-core114-and-sampath).

Answer (score 2):

Try to add schema in module component and check

```
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RoundProgressModule],
schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
    })
```

Comment: not working sir, after add this cannot find name `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA`

Comment: import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core' add this

Comment: `RoundProgressConfig` is allays get the red color

Comment: still not working sir, whats wrong with, i cant understand this

Comment: I never tried this plugin. Just giving answers for you error message. are you getting any errors or it's not rendering properly?

Comment: sir you know any example for ionic `progress bar circle`, i cant find   in google

Comment: see this SVG sample, it's simple and we are using the same in our projects https://codepen.io/JMChristensen/pen/Ablch. share me the Github repository if you can, I will check later today.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158060/discussion-between-core114-and-prithivi-raj).